# Can I use insert() on an empty list in Python?

Tags: python

I'm confused as to how the `insert()` function in Python works. I was trying to reverse a string and I thought I could do that by simply creating a list which stores the characters of the original string in reverse order. Here's my code:-

```
def reverse(text):
    rev = []
    l = len(text) - 1
    for c in text:
        rev.insert(l, c)
        l -= 1
    return rev

print reverse("Hello")
```

Yet the output I get is `['o', 'H', 'l', 'e', 'l']`, which is obviously wrong. 
Any help would be appreciated. Is there something wrong in the logic I've applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert at the start of a list (empty or not), the first argument to `insert()` must be `0`.

**Minimal Code Example**

```
l = [*'Hello']

rev = []
for c in l:
     rev.insert(0, c)

rev
# ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'H']
```

Answer (score 5):

**yes**, you can use *`insert()` on an empty list in python*. that leads directly to the problem with your code:

```
rev = []
rev.insert(3, 'a')  # ['a']
```

if the index is bigger than the length of your list, the item will just be appended. in your code the first insert is `'H'` at position 5; but this will just result in `rev = ['H']`. this is the wrong position for `'H'`!

a remedy would just be to insert at position 0:

```
def reverse(text):
    rev = []
    for c in text:
        rev.insert(0, c)
    return rev
```

(just in case: the simplest way to do that in python is: `'Hello'[::-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

While other's have showed you how to fix your method, I'll explain what was wrong with your previous one.

The problem with your approach is that your list changes each iteration. So the insertion positions of your elements are relative to the current length of the list. Here is a step through of what you for loop is basically doing:

```
>>> rev = []
>>> l = len('Hello') - 1
>>> l
4
>>> # first iteration
>>> rev.insert(l, 'H')
>>> rev
['H']
>>> l -= 1
>>> l
3
>>> # second iteration
>>> rev.insert(l, 'e')
>>> rev
['H', 'e']
>>> l -= 1
>>> l
2
>>> # third iteration
>>> rev.insert(l, 'l')
>>> rev
['H', 'e', 'l']
>>> l -= 1
>>> l
1
>>> # fourth iteration
>>> rev.insert(l, 'l')
>>> rev
['H', 'l', 'e', 'l']
>>> l -= 1
>>> l
0
>>> # Fifth iteration
>>> rev.insert(l, 'o')
>>> rev
['o', 'H', 'l', 'e', 'l']
>>> l -= 1
>>> l
-1
>>> # end
```

As you can see, your insertions position changes based on how the list grows. Sometimes `insert` behaves like `append()`, other times it goes back to behaving like `insert()`.

You can fix this problem by making your insertion position `0`. That way, you always append to the beginning of the list regardless of how the list changes:

```
rev.insert(0, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, lists are **zero-indexed**. So when you do `insert(1,c)`, you are actually inserting in the SECOND position in the list.
To insert at the beginning of the list, use `insert(0,c)`.

Comment: append will always add the element at the end of the list. Since I want to reverse my string, I actually want to go in the other direction, from the final index to the 0th.

Comment: That's where the [::-1] (reversed list) comes in handy. Looping through the inversed list will get the desired output with insert(0,c) or append().

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `deque`:

```
from collections import deque

s = "Hello"

d = deque() #create a deque object

for i in s:
   d.appendleft(i)


print(''.join(d))
```

Output:

```
olleH
```

A deque gives you the option of creating a list mutable at both ends. The method `appendleft()` is the same as `insert(0, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
def reverse(text):
  rev = []
  for c in text:
    rev.insert(0, c)
  return rev

print reverse("Hello")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def reverse(text):
  revText = text[::-1]
  return list(revText)

print reverse("Hello")
```

result

```
['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'H']
```

Comment: An alternative implementation is Ok, but it doesn't answer the question "How to use `insert()`?`"